# How to reselove ambiguity when when using reflection?

Tags: android, kotlin, reflection, ambiguity

I'm  trying to perform the following line in Kotlin:

```
var str: KFunction<String> = String::toUpperCase
```

But compiler says:

> Overload resolution ambiguity. All these functions match.
> public inline fun String.toUpperCase(): String defined in kotlin.text
> public inline fun String.toUpperCase(locale: Locale): String defined in kotlin.text

I thought that writing *KFunction* should overcome the ambiguity since not writing nothing before the *String* in *KFunction* means that the KFunciton shouldn't get parameters and only return a String (which compatible with the function that is defined in  kotlin.text package, but it seems that the compiler want some more info.
I'm also trying the following assignment:

```
    var str: KFunction<java.util.Locale,String> = "some Word"::toUpperCase
```

And getting additional error saying that:

> One type argument expected for interface KFunction

If I will use a method that isn't overloaded (like *toString) , So everything works. For Example:

```
var str: KFunction<String> = String::toString
```

What Am I missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this exactly? What do you expect to be assigned on str

Comment: I have changed the example in the question to *String:: toUpperCase*       .. I'm expecting that I will be able to use str varibale to run a function that get a String/or Locale and perform the toUpperCase that returns a String . If toUpperCase wasn't overloaded and instead of toUpperCase I will write toString for example so everything works

Comment: @IR42, did your try it mate? i'm still getting the old erorr + *"Unresolved reference: KFunction1"*

Comment: @IR42, ok thanks. I was surprised that alt + enter didn't import it automatically. Can you tell me please what is the type the should be at left side of the assignment if i'm trying to get function reference that's bound to an instance:   *val whatShouldIWriteVariable = "abcd"::toUpperCase*  ?

Comment: actually, it is better to use [function types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types) syntax, `var str: (String) -> String = String::toUpperCase` and `() -> String` for instance method reference

Comment: @IR42, I see.. Because it's impossible to use KFunction to solve the ambiguity in the case I have described in my previous comment?      *var str: KFunction<String> = "das"::toUpperCase*

Comment: KFunction is intended for reflection. You would typically get a reference to a KFunction by using a KClass, listing its members, and picking one out of the list by name.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
val str: KFunction2<String,Locale, String> = String::toUpperCase
```